# Inseparable extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Given that $F/K$ is a finite extension of fields and the extension is not separable.

My question is whether we can always find a subfield $L$ such that $K\subset L \subset F$ and $[F:L]=p$, where $p=char(K)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware that there’s a maximal separable extension of $K$ in $F$?

Comment: I know that we can get a maximal separable extension $K_s$ such that $ [F:K_s]$ is a prime power. I thought of taking all elements raised to exponent $ p$ as a candidate for $L$ but couldn't show it is not $F$ or $F$ is degree $p $ over it.

Comment: So you’re reduced to the case that $F$ is purely inseparable (“radicial”) over $K$, say of degree $p^n$. Now let $a\in F\setminus K$, so its $K$-irreducible polynomial is $X^{p^m}-b$ for $b\in K$. If $K(b)=F$, you’re done, and if not, then pull the same trick on $K\supset K(b)$, inductively. This should work.

Comment: I want a subfield $L$ of $F$ such that $[F:L]=p$, not a prime power. I can't see how your comment applies to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re looking for a subfield $L$ that’ll have $[F:L]=p$. First we take the maximal separable extension $K^{\text{sep}}$ of $K$ in $F$, so that $F\supset K^{\text{sep}}$ is totally inseparable, and of finite degree $p^n$. So let’s go for an inductive argument, supposing that $p^m$ is the smallest degree of a proper subfield $F$ with $K^{\text{sep}}\subset F\subset L$ and $[L:F]=p^m$. We want $m=1$.

So we suppose that $[L:F]=p^m$ and take any $a\in L$ that’s not in $F$. Its minimal $F$-polynomial will be $X^{p^k}-b$ for some $k\le m$ and some $b\in F$. If $F(a)$ is a proper subfield of $L$, then we have $[L:F(a)]<[L:F]=p^m$, contradicting minimality of $m$. So we may take $F(a)=L$. If $k=1$ we’re done, but in any case, $F(a^p)$ is a proper subfield of $L$, ’cause if we in fact had $F(a^p)=L$, we’d also have $F(a^{p^i})=L$ for all $i$, and that’s not the case for $i=k$. Thus we take $F(a^p)$ for the desired subfield.

Comment: Great answer.  One can extend the question to ask what extension degrees must occur in such a setup. Say if $[F:K]=p^l$ then, can we say that all $k<l$ such that $\gcd(k,l)=1$   must occur as a degree.

Comment: There is a classification of the intermediate fields when you have an extension $K\supset k$ and $k\supset K^p$, maybe restricted to the case of finite degree. You look at certain derivations, I think $k$-linear derivations of $K$ into $K$. To tell the truth, I’ve forgotten it. But the extensions that are “deeper” in some sense can get very complicated.